# Meaning of "IconResource= ..\.. ,(number)"

Tags: windows, attributes, icons, directory

My first question in Stackoverflow, I'm thinking in making a litle program to edit some folder icons on Windows, I searched for the meaning of the number after the path of the icon but find no answer, the system icons have diferent values, i.e:

Music Folder

```
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-108
```

Pictures Folder

```
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-113
```

When we manually change an icon from a folder,usually is used(to  keep it in a removable media):

`IconResource=..\Icons\icon.ico,0`

There is any influence in that last number? Or it doesn't matter for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.EXE and .DLL files can contain more than one icon. `,0` is the first icon in the file, this syntax can also be used for .ICO files that only contain one icon.

Positive numbers simply refer to the order the icons are stored in the executable file (`,0` is the first, `,1` is the second and `,2` is the third etc.). This order is the same as the order of icons in the standard pick icon dialog in Windows (shortcut properties etc.).

A negative number is the resource id of the icon, this is a number chosen by the author of said executable and **can** be stable over time even if the number if icons changes **if** the author chooses to use stable resource ids.

See also:
[How the shell converts an icon location into an icon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100505-00/?p=14153)